# Likes count doesn't match on website and facebook pages

Tags: facebook

The following website and Facebook page show different 'Like' number counts. The Facebook [page](https://www.facebook.com/customdocksystems) shows 125 'Likes'. The [website](http://www.customdocksystems.com) only shows 18 'Likes'. Why are these numbers not the same? What can we do to make them match?

Comment: could you add more details?

Answer (score 0):

The like button on your website needs to refer to your facebook page. To do this just change

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.customdocksystems.com" data-send="true" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

to

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/customdocksystems" data-send="true" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false" data-colorscheme="dark"></div>
```

and the like button on your website will show the number of likes that your Facebook page has. Furthermore, when a user clicks the like button on your website they will like the Facebook page so you can keep in touch with them through that.

The catch to all this is that when people click the like button on your website after this change, the story that is shared to Facebook will direct users to your Facebook Page instead of your website.

Check out "Can I link the Like button to my Facebook page?" on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ for more information.